# nginx rewrite rules to match apache rewrite for php-login

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

Background:
I was using this php application for my project
https://github.com/panique/php-login/

When i started, i started with apache and completed my whole project.
but when i have to push this to production server, they only support nginx.

i tried to convert rewrites rules, it still not working
Any help is appreciated
Apache .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

what i tried with nginx (consider dist is the folder where my application resides)

```
if ($request_uri ~ .*dist.*) {     
rewrite ^(.+)$ http://example.com/app/dist/index.php?url=$1; }
```

i tried this both

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
      rewrite ^/dist/(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 last;
      }
```

I also contacted the github owner, he being an total Ahole about supporting nginx.

Comment: There are tons of examples converting apache to nginx. I guess, in this case you should use `try_files` http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Front_Controller_Pattern_based_packages

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, but I ignored the `-l` flag cause I don't really know what's the nginx corresponding syntax for it, and I don't really thing it's important.

```
location /whatever {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
}
location @fallback{
  rewrite ^ /index.php?url=$1&$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[nginx try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) is what you are looking for. You can take a look at the [configuration examples](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration) (search for php on the site) to get a better understanding about nginx+php.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app/dist/index.php?url=$uri$args;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Change `rtrim` to `trim` in line 74 of `application/libs/Bootstrap.php`.

This then makes it compatible with the very popular and fast growing nginx server, without breaking compatibility with Apache.

For more info, see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/panique/php-mvc/issues/55

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: @John it is the same question.